Why is my laundry standpipe overflowing?
The problem is with the pipe labelled 1 in the picture. It is the pipe through which the washing machine discards water. And every two days or so, water leaks through it It's a PVC pipe which is coming out of the floor slightly. It overflows from the top when the washing machine is discarding water
The plumber has been called several times just thought it to be a clog in the main pipe under the floor and has cleared it with a machine. However, just after 3 days it started leaking again. Moreover, not many things come out of the main pipe when cleaned.
I really don't think it's the clogs causing the problem. Any help or ideas would be appreciated.
Edit: Removed the mistaken part that said water leaked through the point where the pipe touched the floor.
.


Please define leaks. Is there water coming from a joint? Is the water backing up out of the drainage pipe?

If the pipe was in good condition, even with a clog the water should only come out/leak at the top.   Does it leak only when using the washer, or leaks when not using the washer?  Either have a bad/loose joint or the pipe is broken or ground water is making its way up there(but should be constant).

@crip659 the pipe leaks only from the top. Leaks only when using the washer and I somehow think that water is making its way up.

Where in your sketch is your vent?  Also, what are your pipe diameters?

Is this a recent problem? Did something change, like did you get a new washing machine?

You have a clog somewhere.
The plumber might not have gone far enough down the drain to find it yet
The other idea is the is a clog in the plumbing vent system.
A bird's nest/leaves might be blocking air into the plumbing pipes, making water draining much slower.
Washing machines pump out a lot of water in a short time, so the drain  line usually will be affected first if the plumbing system is not working well.

Since the kitchen sink also uses that same pipe, wouldn't a clog cause that to overflow as well. And a problem in the plumbing system would cause a problem everywhere. Isn't it so? Correct me if I am wrong though

@PadmaBarik   It is the large amount of water draining in a short time from a washing machine.  Most sinks do not force as much water down the drain as fast.  It is like turning a bucket of water upside down instead of pouring the water out.  You probably only have a partial clog, not a full one, either in the drain or vent.

Thanks for the help. I will ask the plumber to try and find the clog


"a PVC pipe which is coming out of the floor slightly"

You need to install a larger standpipe.
In my area of the world, a large standpipe is typically installed. The standpipe will usually be much taller than what you describe (often 30" tall).
Newer washing machines can often pump out water at a rate that is too fast for old waste pipes to accommodate, necessitating a large (in diameter and perhaps height) standpipe to hold the discharged water while the water drains out.
Example: 

I also thought about this. But with such a long pipe. Can the washing machine outlet provide enough pressure to lift the water up. It's not that strong

Yes, it generally can. If you have the washing machine installation manual it may specify max height for your unit. I believe that common code is max height at 42" above trap weir (the top of the water level in the trap), or above the floor if trap is below the floor. You can always make it bigger in diameter, and thus capable of holding more water.
